# Having problems exporting Genesis + Supersuit in .fbx format from Daz 3D

Tags: fbx

I created a new scene. Loaded the Michael 5 Hero character. Added the Supersuit. Then posed the M5 character using "M5 Walking 1" pose from the "M5 General Poses" collection.

My problem is that whenever I import the fbx file into another software (like Maya or Unity), my genesis figure appears to be in that pose (M5 Walking 1), but the supersuit still remains in the default T-pose!

Please tell me how to rectify this.

Comment: Have you tried parenting the suit to the character?

Comment: I dragged 'Supersuit' and placed it inside 'Genesis', if that's what you meant. It didn't solve my problem. :-(

Comment: You have given few details. I can't see the rig, get some screenshots it could help us solve the problem. Be a bit more specific about the model... Saying that you have a superman model and his cape doesn't fit is not accurate. Are both meshes in the same format?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally got it to work. Export the character in FBX format with the following attributes checked:

•Figures
•Morphs
•Embed Textures
•Merge Clothing into Figure Skeleton (I was missing this one previously)
•Allow Degraded Skinning
•Allow Degraded Scaling